# EJB3 ctx.lookup ClassCastException

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-8, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

I am trying to use a simple stateless sesssion bean but I have problem to access to my Bean. I got ClassCastException !

I have a maven EJB module contains:

```
//My remote interface
@Remote
public interface ServiceRemote {
    public String getBeanName();
}

//My local interface
@Local
public interface ServiceLocal {
    public String getBeanName();
}

//My Session bean
@Stateless
public class Service implements ServiceLocal, ServiceRemote {
    public String getBeanName() {
        return "Service"; 
    }
}
```

This project is deployed on Jboss AS 6

```
11:03:21,159 INFO  [org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
11:03:21,887 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=Service,service=EJB3
11:03:21,887 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: metier.Service ejbName: Service
11:03:21,891 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.jndiregistrar.JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    Service/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    Service/remote-metier.ServiceRemote - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface
    Service/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
    Service/local-metier.ServiceLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

My client is a maven java application

I added to my client pom.xml the EJB project as dependency:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

And a jboss-ejb-client

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

My main class :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:1099");

            Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);

            Object obj = (Object) ctx.lookup("Service/remote");

            System.out.println("service.getClass(): " + obj.getClass());
            System.out.println("service.toString(): " + obj.toString());

            ServiceRemote myService = (ServiceRemote) obj;
            myService.getBeanName();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When i run my client i had java.lang.ClassCastException :

My console outup:

```
service.getClass(): class javax.naming.Reference
service.toString(): Reference Class Name: Proxy for: metier.ServiceRemote
Type: ProxyFactoryKey
Content: ProxyFactory/mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Service/Service/remote
Type: EJB Container Name
Content: jboss.j2ee:jar=mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=Service,service=EJB3
Type: Proxy Factory is Local
Content: false
Type: Remote Business Interface
Content: metier.ServiceRemote
Type: Remoting Host URL
Content: socket://127.0.0.1:3873/?timeout=300000

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to metier.ServiceRemote
```

Can someone help me, i don't know where is the problem to access to my session bean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException` from `javax.naming.Reference` is a sign you don't have the `ObjectFactory` class on your client ClassPath.

I see you have included jbossall-client in your maven dependencies, but you also need all the jars that are listed in the `MANIFEST.MF` of `jbossall-client.jar`, in the client's classpath.

- [Solution found here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/2359)
- [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)